# I need to add an extra value to the fields in the formadata displayed via a javascript form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to achieve this:

I would like to create a form that gather the data input from the user and print it on screen. So far I have achieved almost OK with the code snippet below, however, I need the "textone" and "textTWO" fields to display an additional data value of "task one" and "task two" (before their value)

```js
function testVariable() {
    var strText = document.getElementById("textone").value;          
    var strText1 = document.getElementById("textTWO").value;
    var result = strText + ' ' + strText1;
    document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent = result;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textone" />
<input type="text" id="textTWO" />
<button  onclick="testVariable()">Submit</button> <br />
<span id="spanResult"></span>
```

So, my question is: how to change the JS in order to print on screen "task one" before the result of the field "task one" and same for "task two"

Comment: `var result = "task one: " + strText + ...`

Comment: You just need to prepend the strings you define in `result` using the same string concatenation syntax you already are...?

Comment: That works great, thanks....what if I wanted the results to be each on one line (like a line break between task one and task two)....is it achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only add labels where you return your values like :

```
  var result = 'Task one: ' + strText + ' AND TastTwo: ' + strText1;
```

```js
function testVariable() {
  var strText = document.getElementById("textone").value;
  var strText1 = document.getElementById("textTWO").value;
  var result = 'Task one: ' + strText + ' AND TastTwo: ' + strText1;
  document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textone" />
<input type="text" id="textTWO" />
<button onclick="testVariable()">Submit</button> <br />
<span id="spanResult"></span>
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's what I needed. Many thanks for the prompt response